# Assert windows closed in Coded UI Tests

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I'm developing a set of coded UI tests for a WPF project.  Does anyone know how to assert that a window was closed?  I can't seem to check any properties of the window after it is gone.  Should I assert the UI element is null, maybe?

Comment: `Assert.IsNull` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITestControl` class has a method called `WaitForControlNotExist` that did the trick!