# Coded UI Test - waiting for running application to finish during the test

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, gui-testing, window-handles

I am trying to create test for my-app using **coded ui test** with visual studio ultimate 2012, in my-app i run another app ( cmd window is opened during "another app" running).
i want to wait until this "another app" finish running and then to check some results.
how can i do that?

if someone know how to control window using **coded ui test** i think it may help, until now i didn't find an example of that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489500/assert-windows-closed-in-coded-ui-tests . You might check for the non-existence of the application window or the command window.

Comment: yes you are right, but i don't know how to let UITestControl object wait for specific window to close! can you give simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find a way.

my problem was to control and wait for the cmd window which related to "another app" execution.

i run the system and the VS recorder, and start recording when cmd window of the another app pop up and then i maximized the window and stop recording, i did this to get automatic generated code to control this window, the code i got:

```
    public void WaitUntilAnotherappFinish()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinWindow uIAnotherppWindow = this.UIAnotherappWindow
        #endregion

        // Maximize window 
        uIAnotherppWindow.Maximized = this.WaitUntilAnotherappFinishParams.UIAnotherappWindowMaximized;
    }
```

so i replace the maximize window command line to waiting for the window not exist:

```
    public void WaitUntilAnotherappFinish()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinWindow uIAnotherppWindow = this.UIAnotherappWindow
        #endregion

        // wait for window to close 
        uIAnotherppWindow.WaitForControlNotExist();
    }
```

and this exactly did what i want :).

***important note:*** be careful that this file is an auto generated file so your changes may be undo! solve this by implementing your own method in your test file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Like what @AdrianHHH suggested try the UIMap.AnotherAppUIWindow.WaitForControlNotExist(); Just add that line of code with the proper element
2. Throw a "while" within a try-catch and just wait, catch the proper exception being thrown, e.g element could not be found exception

   ```
   Try
   {
       while(UIMap.AnotherAppUIWindow.Exists)
       {
          //Do nothing
       }

   }catch(Exception)
   {
      //Window no longer exists
   }
   ```